# How do I hook a moment when all views are measured in my Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to know correct widths, heights and positions of some of the views in my `Activity` ASAP after `onResume`. Where can I place this code in my Activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oddly, I get to reuse an answer the same day I make it:

You could set a global layout listener on the view tree in your `onResume()` and do your diddling in there.

```
final ViewTreeObserver vto = myView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // do layout tweaking based on measurements

        // remove the listener... or we'll be doing this a lot.
        vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to use `vto.isAlive()` and call `getViewTreeObserver()` again, otherwise it crashed with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: This ViewTreeObserver is not alive`. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Ah! Nice find and glad it helped. Best of luck.

Comment: @AndreyNovikov can you show how exactly you did it ?

Comment: @Danpe, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39001731/2914140