# Remove listener from ViewTreeObserver

Tags: android

I need to listen for exact one global layouting event to initially set correct scrolling positions. After searching a little why my calls to `scrollTo(x,y)` seem to be ignored I discovered these can only be called in an meaningful way once the whole layout is known. So I am registering a `GlobalLayoutListener` and defer my call to `scrollTo()`.

The problem is, that I only want to do this scrolling once. So I figured I could simply call `removeGlobalOnLayoutListener()` to stop listening. That resulted in a Exception: `IllegalStateException: This ViewTreeObserver is not alive, call getViewTreeObserver() again`. So I thought I am fine, if the Observer is not alive it won't fire any events. But unfortunately it does: My view is scrolled every time the layout somehow changes.

My current iteration of the code looks like this. What could I change to make sure the call to `scrollToGridPos()` only takes place once? I know I could just add a local field `mHasFired`  to the inner class but that seems like very dirty hack to me ...

```
final ViewTreeObserver vto = mLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        scrollToGridPos(getCenterPoint(), false);
        if (vto.isAlive()) {
            vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It does not seems like a hack to me. Alternatively you could also do the same inside `View.onLayout` if you can override it. This seems more the way to do it to me.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You should just be using `mLayout.getViewTreeObserver()` in `onGlobalLayout()`, rather than trying to access the *old* one. Eg.

```
mLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        scrollToGridPos(getCenterPoint(), false);
        mLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);        
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks great, but `removeGlobalOnLayoutListener` is deprecated. Is there any other solution for removing the listener?

Comment: I am using removeOnGlobalLayoutListener()

Comment: And usually they say what to use in case of deprecation, should be stated in Java docs.