# RecyclerView with LoadMore Button on The Top Like Facebook Comment

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

I want to implement list view like facebook comments that able to load previous comments on top. Here screenshoot of facebook comments.

[image]

So, on facebook app, when I clicked button "Load previous comments" it append data on the first position of the list without changing listView state/position.

In my project I use RecylcerView with loadmore button on the header. On the header, I put "Load Previous button". When the button is clicked, it put new data into the list.

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
     list.add(0, "New data on top");
 }
```

After new data appended to list, I tried calling notifyDataSetChanged to make change happen, and call smoothScrollToPosition on my recycler view to make it scrolled into the first position before new data added.

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(10);
```

But the problem is it scrolling up. So I wanna make RecylerView stay on the last position before new data added just like facebook comment.

Can anybody suggest me how to implement this?

Comment: Hey did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Swipe to refresh layout](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html) you might want to use for this. Note however that there is no button but an spinner image that is dismissed automatically.

EDIT: 
Just realized that this does not answer the question. You might want to check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580723/how-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-recyclerview-scrolltoposition-doesnt-work) that is a possible duplicate.