# Focus EditText from add item in RecycleView

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, android-recyclerview

I have got an app where I use a `RecycleView` with `CardViews`. The `CardView` contains an `EditText` now when I add a new `CardView` to the `RecycleView` the `EditText` should be focused and the keyboard should appear.

How can I achieve that? I have tried to add some code in the `onBindViewHolder`:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(TodoViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ...
    if(holder.tvDescription.requestFocus()) {
        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    }
    ...
}
```

Or while the creation of the `ViewHolder` but it hasn't worked.

```
public class TodoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected CheckBox cbDone;
    protected EditText tvDescription;
    protected FloatingActionButton btnDelete;

    public TodoViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cbDone = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbDone);
        tvDescription = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
        btnDelete = (FloatingActionButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        if(tvDescription.requestFocus()) {
            window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `AdapterCode` with a solution:

```
public abstract class ArrayAdapter<T, VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {

    private static final String TAG = "CustomArrayAdapter";

    private List<T> mObjects;

    public ArrayAdapter(final List<T> objects) {
        mObjects = objects;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified object at the end of the array.
     *
     * @param object The object to add at the end of the array.
     */
    public void add(final T object) {
        mObjects.add(object);
        notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);
    }

    /**
     * Remove all elements from the list.
     */
    public void clear() {
        final int size = getItemCount();
        mObjects.clear();
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mObjects.size();
    }

    public T getItem(final int position) {
        return mObjects.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public List<T> getItems() {
        return mObjects;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the position of the specified item in the array.
     *
     * @param item The item to retrieve the position of.
     * @return The position of the specified item.
     */
    public int getPosition(final T item) {
        return mObjects.indexOf(item);
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the specified object at the specified index in the array.
     *
     * @param object The object to insert into the array.
     * @param index  The index at which the object must be inserted.
     */
    public void insert(final T object, int index) {
        mObjects.add(index, object);
        notifyItemInserted(index);

    }

    /**
     * Removes the specified object from the array.
     *
     * @param object The object to remove.
     */
    public void remove(T object) {
        final int position = getPosition(object);
        remove(position);
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position >= mObjects.size()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "remove: index=" + position);
        } else {
            mObjects.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sorts the content of this adapter using the specified comparator.
     *
     * @param comparator The comparator used to sort the objects contained in this adapter.
     */
    public void sort(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        Collections.sort(mObjects, comparator);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, getItemCount());
    }
}
```

The implemented `Adapter`:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Todo, RecyclerViewAdapter.TodoViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";
    private Todo selectedItem;
    private final Window window;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Todo> todos, Window window) {
        super(todos);
        this.window = window;
    }

    public Todo getSelectedItem() {
        return selectedItem;
    }

    public class TodoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
        protected CheckBox cbDone;
        protected EditText tvDescription;
        protected FloatingActionButton btnDelete;

        public TodoViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cbDone = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbDone);
            tvDescription = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            btnDelete = (FloatingActionButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

            itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Send to:");
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "all");

            Log.d(TAG, "view id: " + v.getId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Todo object) {
        object.shouldBeFocused = true;
        super.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public TodoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.todo_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new TodoViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final TodoViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Todo todo = getItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        holder.cbDone.setChecked(todo.isChecked);
        holder.tvDescription.setText(todo.description);

        holder.tvDescription.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // Do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // Do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                todo.description = s.toString();
            }
        });

        holder.cbDone.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onCheckedChanged called: isDone=" + isChecked);
                todo.isChecked = isChecked;
            }
        });

        holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onClick called: remove todo.");
                remove(todo);
            }
        });

        View.OnLongClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                selectedItem = todo;
                return false;
            }
        };

        holder.cbDone.setOnLongClickListener(onClickListener);
        holder.tvDescription.setOnLongClickListener(onClickListener);
        holder.btnDelete.setOnLongClickListener(onClickListener);

        if (todo.shouldBeFocused) {
            holder.tvDescription.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (holder.tvDescription.requestFocus()) {
                        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
                        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) holder.tvDescription.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(holder.tvDescription, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                    }
                }
            });
            todo.shouldBeFocused = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The `Todo`:

```
public class Todo implements Serializable {

    // The creationDate is not used at the moment
    protected Date creationDate;
    protected String description;
    protected boolean isChecked;
    protected boolean shouldBeFocused;

    public Todo(String description) {
        this.description = description;
        this.creationDate = new Date();
    }

    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public String getDescription() { return description; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return creationDate + ": " + description + " state[" + isChecked + "]";
    }
}
```

And in the `MainActivity` the add method:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        adapter.add(new Todo(""));
        int count = adapter.getItemCount();
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(count - 1);
    }
});
```

Problem when testing some solution:

[image: Correct behavior at the beginning]
[image: Still correct behavior]
[image: Here you can see, that some entries are duplicated in the list]

Comment: How about using `holder.tvDescription.setSelection(position)`? Does that work?

Comment: @Razor this throughs an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is because you call `requestFocus()` too early, cause your view doesn't appear on the screen yet. Also you should add some flag, when you're adding a new element - should you request focus on this view or not, to prevent all previous views in `RecyclerView` be focused. Assuming you add a new `CardView` to the end of `RecyclerView`, so your add method of `Adapter` should be like this:

```
public void addToEnd(Model item) {
    item.shouldBeFocused = true;
    dataset.add(item);
    notifyItemInserted(dataset.size() - 1);
}
```

And then in your `onBindViewHolder()` do something like this:

```
Model item = dataset.get(position);
...
if (item.shouldBeFocused) {
    holder.tvDescription.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (holder.tvDescription.requestFocus()) {
                window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) holder.tvDescription.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(holder.tvDescription, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            }
        }
    });
    item.shouldBeFocused = false;
}
...
```

Also you would probably need to scroll to the last position of your `RecyclerView` to call your `onBindViewHolder()` for the new added element. You can do this for example by [setStackFromEnd = true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27069845/3225458) line.

**UPDATE:**

Your problem is that you're adding `TextWatcher` inside `onBindViewHolder` method, firstly it's very expensive operation, and secondly you're saving entered text to the `final` reference, that's why your `RecyclerView` gives inappropriate results after.

So, try to create your custom `TextWatcher`, that keeps position of current item in `Adapter` **first**:

```
private static class PositionTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private int position;

    public void updatePosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        // no op
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        final Todo todo = getItem(position);
        todo.description = charSequence.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        // no op
    }
}
```

**Then** add it to your `EditText` in `ViewHolder`'s constructor, when `onCreateViewHolder` will be called:

```
@Override
public TodoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.todo_layout, viewGroup, false);
    return new TodoViewHolder(view, new PositionTextWatcher());
}

public class TodoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
    protected CheckBox cbDone;
    protected EditText tvDescription;
    protected FloatingActionButton btnDelete;
    protected PositionTextWatcher positionTextWatcher;

     public TodoViewHolder(View itemView, PositionTextWatcher positionTextWatcher) {
        super(itemView);

        cbDone = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbDone);
        tvDescription = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
        btnDelete = (FloatingActionButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        this.positionTextWatcher = positionTextWatcher;
        tvDescription.addTextChangedListener(this.positionTextWatcher);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Send to:");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "all");

        Log.d(TAG, "view id: " + v.getId());
    }
}
```

And **finally**, instead of adding a new `TextWatcher` each time in `onBindViewHolder()`, just update the position in your custom `TextWatcher`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final TodoViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Todo todo = getItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    ...
    holder.cbDone.setChecked(todo.isChecked);
    holder.positionTextWatcher.updatePosition(position);
    holder.tvDescription.setText(todo.description);
    ...
}
```

This should work like a charm! Got that solution from [this perfect answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31860393/3225458), so check it for more background.

Comment: it focuses correct but a problem with displaying entries duplicated appears, as far as there are more elements in the `RecyclerView` so that scrolling is needed. I think it depends with the view recycling.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. Could you explain more or make a video? Is the problem with the `setStackFromEnd` ?

Comment: I tried your solution and added the images to the question, as you can see there it appears that some entries are duplicated (but they are only duplicated in the view not in the `List`).

Comment: I guess the problem is that you don't save your entered data correctly, hence some values are duplicated after recycling. You could show all code  of your Adapter, if you want us to understand the problem :)

Comment: Or you can try `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount())` after you add a new element to the adapter, instead of `setStackFromEnd = true` line, but I'm not sure that it's the problem

Comment: I added the code to the question, I hope it helps you to understand my problem

Comment: I tried the update but it still does not work :/ the most `EditText` get empty when I scroll and the view does also have duplicates.

Comment: So, did you remove `addTextChangeListener` in `onBindViewHolder` method?

Comment: Do you have your code somewhere? I have my code here: https://github.com/Blackjack92/TodoManager

Comment: I see you are not properly updating your custom `TextWatcher`. It should keep position, but not reference to the object from your dataset. It's recycling things. So just try to change it exactly to my example.

Comment: i only changed this code before the change i had exactly your code and it had the same problem

Comment: So finally I got it, it seems the problem has been solved by replacing `setText` and `addTextChangeListener` with each other. I've created a pull request to your repository, so check and test it, for me now it works.

Comment: So @KevinWallis did you check my pull request with solution?

Comment: I will do it today evening, I had no time up to now :/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ...

    // If this ViewHolder needs keyboard focus, execute below code.
    holder.itemView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                holder.itemView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                holder.itemView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }

            EditText editText = holder.tvDescription;
            editText.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) editText.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(editText, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This does not work, there appears a problem with the `RecyclerView` some entries are displayed multiple times and also the `EditText` is not focused.