# Android: Scroll to the last item in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, scrollbar

I understand there were some discussions regarding what I tried to resolve on SO. Here are a couple that I've found so far: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875061/scroll-recyclerview-to-show-selected-item-on-top) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580723/how-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-recyclerview-scrolltoposition-doesnt-work).

The suggestions worked for me to some extend but unfortunately didn't resolve the whole problem of mine. Let me elaborate:

Simply put I have a list of items that I put in a RecyclerView and I wanted to scroll to a certain item after I clicked a button on the top menu bar. To simply things, I just wanted to scroll to the last item when clicked, for now.

I tried to put the code right after retrieving the reference to RecyclerView, like this (listView is a RecyclerView):

```
    listView = (RecyclerView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.list_section);
    listView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager mListViewManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    listView.setLayoutManager(mListViewManager);
    listView.scrollToPosition(entries.size()-1);
```

This worked. However, if I tried to do the following, it didn't, please pay attention to the comments below:

```
 //enter this block when the menu item was clicked
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     //mPagerAdapter is a reference to a FragmentStatePagerAdapter extended class
     mPagerAdapter.highlightPosition(list.size()-1);
 }

//selSchedListFragment is a reference to a Fragment extended class
public void highlightPosition(int pos){
  selSchedListFragment.highlightPosition(pos);
};
```

and inside the Fragment class is how highlightPosition is defined:

```
public void highlightPosition(int pos) {
    //listView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(pos);
    listView.smoothScrollToPosition(pos);
    //listView.scrollToPosition(pos);
    //LinearLayoutManager llm = (LinearLayoutManager) listView.getLayoutManager();
    //llm.scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos , 29);

}
```

You will notice that I tried a few techniques in the core function of highlightPosition, but none worked.

There must be something that is missing, can anyone please suggest.

Comment: you should get adapter count and set it for scroll to recycler view it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> In onOptionsItemSelected method do

```
mPagerAdapter.highlightPosition(listView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

For scrolling in listview you can use the native functions

For a direct scroll:

```
getListView().setSelection(21);
```

For a smooth scroll:

```
listview.smoothScrollToPosition(21);
```

Answer (score 0):

### This works for me to move the recycler view focus to last row

```
 mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerView,null, finalCustomItems.size()-1);
```