# Make recycler view only start scrolling once display is bottomed out

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an activity that is basically like `Imgur` - there is a picture that takes up the entire screen, then there are comments below (that also take up one full screen) I want the recycler view to only start scrolling once the red (the display) has hit the bottom.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Try to look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580723/how-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-recyclerview-scrolltoposition-doesnt-work

Comment: @Mwongera how are the questions even related?