# Android recyclerview load more data on scroll up

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm developing a one chat application in this basically I'm loading last 50 posts but now my requirement is   to load older posts when user scrolls up. I know that how to load the more data when scrolls end by using end less scroll. Please suggest me how to load more data when I scroll up?

Comment: there's definitely a lot of tutorials on stuff like this out there. Used this a while ago: http://www.devexchanges.info/2017/02/android-recyclerview-dynamically-load.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use the older answer from the SO. Just set `setStackFromEnd=true` or `setReverseLayout=true` so that **LinearLayoutManager** will layout items from end.

Here's an original answer from the older questions https://stackoverflow.com/a/27069845/6845290