# How to scroll android recyclerview quickly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling

I have a `recyclerview` with over 800 items in it.

When the `recyclerview` loads on the screen, i want the bottom of the list to display
but it does the scrolling animation, which could take a while...

How to do it without animation?

Answer (score 0):

Use `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(int position)` and enter the last position of your recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(items.size() - 1);
```

Or checkout another way : https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/27069845

Comment: this does not work - either the view gets scrolled to the middle, or does not scroll at all

Comment: Did you check out the other solution : setReverseLayout=true ?

Comment: i did, it screws up other parts for me