# Force ScrollView at Bottom on Start of Activity

Tags: java, android, layout, android-scrollview

I have created a chatroom where user can discuss on several Topic. I'm using a Scrollview inside RelativeLayout which contains chatConversation
The Porblem is when user opens app then he has to scroll to the Bottom HImself to chat or view the new chat discussion.

How can I force scrollview to start at Bottom when activity is started..

[image]

Below is my layout file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_chat"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#F0791F"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_people_outline_black_24dp"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_send"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msg_input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_send"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_send"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_send"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="Write a message" />

    <ScrollView
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_send"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_chat"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn_send"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_send">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:autoLink="all" />
    </ScrollView>
    <View
        android:layout_above="@+id/msg_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I already tried using

```html
final ScrollView scrollLayout = ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView));

scrollLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollLayout.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work either.

Please Help

Comment: I recommend using a RecyclerView with an item for each message, instead of one single TextView. You'll use fewer resources, and you can simply set it to start at the end by default https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580723/how-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-recyclerview-scrolltoposition-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

How are you displaying the messages? With a While Loop?

Last line of the while loop should be...

```
    mScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

mScrollView or whatever name you gave to the ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

I think you're appending the messages in a single `TextView` (correct me if I'm wrong).
Check if you are invoking `fullScroll()` after you are finished appending all the text in your `TextView`.

```
for (String oneMessage : messageList){
     myTextView.append(oneMessage);
     myTextView.append("\n");
     ....
     ....
}
//Scroll to bottom
scrollLayout.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
            boolean success = scrollLayout.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
            Log.d("Auto Scroll", success ? "Done" : "Failed"); 
     }
});
```

Let me know if this fixed your issue!