# How to make RecyclerView scroll to last position in onCreate?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, viewmodel, smooth-scrolling

I was trying to just make the RecyclerView move to last position when the fragment is started, but cant find a solution. The code below works just fine when a new "Pagina" in inserted in database, it moves to last position. But, if I close and reopen it goes back to the top. So, how to make the smoothscroll work when the fragment is created?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    appDatabase = AppDatabase.getDatabase(requireContext())

    val smoothScroller = object : LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
        override fun getVerticalSnapPreference(): Int = SNAP_TO_START
    }
    viewModelo = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModelo::class.java)
    // Create the observer which updates the UI.
    val listPaginas = Observer <List<Pagina>> {
        // Update the UI, in this case, a TextView.

        recyclerViewAdapter?.addItens(it)  
            if (it.size < 1) {               
            smoothScroller.targetPosition = it.size
            } else {
               smoothScroller.targetPosition = it.size-1
        }      

        recyclerView?.layoutManager?.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller)
    }

    viewModelo?.todasPaginas()?.observe(this, listPaginas)

}
```

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27069845/6676310) answer I think it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below changes, it worked!

```
LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(Application.Context);
manager.setStackFromEnd(true); 
mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(manager);
```

Comment: It alligns with the bottom of the row, not the top. But it works, thank you.