# Scroll to the bottom of the Recycler View problem

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580723/how-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-recyclerview-scrolltoposition-doesnt-work) to move to the bottom of the recycler view when user hit send button to send text in EditText. It works well if I input a single line of EditText, however if the EditText has multiple lines in it, the `smoothScrollToPosition(message_container.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)` wont work properly. Assume that my EditText has 4 lines, so the view just scrolls to the first line, not the end of the EditText. Is there any workaround for this? thank kiu.

Comment: can you share your design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a mistake that I put the recycler view inside a scroll view, so the code I used above didn't work like expected, just remove the scroll view and everything is normal again.

Answer (score 0):

```
 item_recyclerview.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recycler, int dx, int dy) {

                if (!shouldScroll) {
                    recycler.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    item_recyclerview.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: could you please more specific? what is shouldScroll?

Comment: shouldScroll is boolean make it false or you can remove it will work