# Load More RecyclerView Error Cannot Call this method

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need help for this load more RecycleView, I create 'Recyclerview', first, limit 5 data and showing, but when I scroll until the end no 'ProgressBar' showing and the next data now showing, I check the 'logcat' no error only warning

this my load more function

```
private void loadMore() {
        arraylist.add(null);
        mListadapter.notifyItemInserted(arraylist.size() - 1);


        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                arraylist.remove(arraylist.size() - 1);
                int scrollPosition = arraylist.size();
                mListadapter.notifyItemRemoved(scrollPosition);
                int currentSize = scrollPosition;
                int nextLimit = currentSize + 5;
                Log.e("currentSize",""+currentSize);
                Log.e("nextLimit",""+nextLimit);
                if(nextLimit <= DataNoteImformation.id.length) {
                    while (currentSize + 1 <= nextLimit) {
                        DataNote wp2 = new DataNote(
                                DataNoteImformation.id[currentSize],
                                DataNoteImformation.branchArray[currentSize],
                                DataNoteImformation.assetcodeArray[currentSize],
                                DataNoteImformation.customerArray[currentSize],
                                DataNoteImformation.licenseplateArray[currentSize]
                        );
                        arraylist.add(wp2);
                        currentSize++;
                    }
                }else {
                    while (currentSize + 1 <= DataNoteImformation.id.length) {
                        DataNote wp2 = new DataNote(
                                DataNoteImformation.id[currentSize],
                                DataNoteImformation.branchArray[currentSize],
                                DataNoteImformation.assetcodeArray[currentSize],
                                DataNoteImformation.customerArray[currentSize],
                                DataNoteImformation.licenseplateArray[currentSize]
                        );
                        arraylist.add(wp2);
                        currentSize++;
                    }
                }
                mListadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                isLoading = false;
            }
        }, 2000);


    }
```

and the warning in logcat

```
W/RecyclerView: Cannot call this method in a scroll callback. Scroll callbacks might be run during a measure & layout pass where you cannot change theRecyclerView data. Any method call that might change the structure of the RecyclerView or the adapter contents should be postponed to the next frame.
```

and this example data

```
public class DataNoteImformation {

    public static String[] branchArray = {"Depok","Jakarta","Bekasi","Jakarta","Jakarta","Bekasi","Bogor","Jakarta","Bekasi","Jakarta"};
    public static String[] assetcodeArray = {"0092","0084","0091","0084","0084","0078","0089","0073","0027","0021"};
    public static String[] customerArray = {"Kevin Sanjaya","Indah Permata","Riyan","Puri Setiawan","Herman","Iwan","Ratna","Agus","Danang","Ujang"};
    public static String[] licenseplateArray = {"B 9829 SK","B 8294 LK","B 9090 NBA","B 7627 SKA","B 7637 SAK","B 6763 KIK","F 7287 NB","F8792KI","B8273KD","B7728KSI"};
    public static String[] id = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
}
```

how to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recyclerview - cannot call this method in a scroll callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944005/recyclerview-cannot-call-this-method-in-a-scroll-callback)

Comment: [Use this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview) to implement Pagination .