# Method of view, called when view element was displayed on the screen the first time?

Tags: android

I need to get the correct coordinates from the method of View.
getLocationOnScreen (locationOnScreen). But in the method View.onCreate() view created yet. What method can I get the correct position of view relative to Activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final ViewTreeObserver vto = myView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // ...
        vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }
}
```

From: [How do I hook a moment when all views are measured in my Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150454/how-do-i-hook-a-moment-when-all-views-are-measured-in-my-activity)